# Play local music files using djs v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I know a lot of people already asked how to play music from youtube in discord voice channel, but I can't find anything about playing local files on djs version 13.2.0!
I tried using this code:

```js
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const { createAudioResource, StreamType, createAudioPlayer, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice'); 
joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        }); 
message.guild.me.voice.setRequestToSpeak(true);
let resource = createAudioResource(join(../music/audio.mp3, 'audio.mp3')); 
const player = createAudioPlayer(); 

player.play(resource);
```

When I try to `eval()` it - my bot joins the channel (stage channel) and says everything worked, but it's not playing anything! How can I make my bot play local music files in stage channel?

Comment: Shouldn't `../music/audio.mp3` be a string, try `createAudioResource(join('..', 'music', 'audio.mp3')); `

Comment: @Elitezen Also not working, I tried logging every step in console and it says everything worked, but I still can't hear any music playing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.

Firstly, the path is completely wrong. It is not a string and even if you try to change it to a string it will be invalid as the first argument ends with `audio.mp3`, and the second one is `audio.mp3`. Use this path instead:

```js
let resource = createAudioResource(join('..', 'music', 'audio.mp3'));
```

Secondly, you are playing audio in the player, but not the voice connection. You must *subscribe* to the audio player.

This should be the final code:

```js
const player = createAudioPlayer()
joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
}).subscribe(player)
message.guild.me.voice.setRequestToSpeak(true);
let resource = createAudioResource(join('..', 'music', 'audio.mp3'));

player.play(resource)
```