# discord.js bot playing audio but no sound?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

I was planning to add some voice features to my discord bot, but for some reason when I run my code, it doesn't make sound *while discord does show the green circle around my bot, showing that it's making sound*. It also does't log any errors or anything else, does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Code:

```js
        if (command == "soundtest") {
            mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
                const { voice } = msg.member

                if (voice.channelID) {
                    const vc = voice.channel
                    // console.log(channel)
                    try {
                        vc.join().then(connection => {
                            connection.play(path.join(__dirname, 'Bastille_Pompeii.mp3'))
                        })
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.log("error")
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                } else {
                    msg.channel.send(`You must join a voice channel to use this command`)
                }
            })
        }
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play local music files using djs v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607756/play-local-music-files-using-djs-v13)

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft OP seems to be using v12, which you can tell by them joining with `VoiceChannel.join`

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft I tried that, but didn't work, changed the line in my code to `                            connection.play(path.join('..', 'musicfiles', 'Bastille_Pompeii.mp3'))`, as the file is called Bastille_Pompeii.mp3 and is located in the folder 'musicfiles' inside the parent folder of the script i'm in

Comment: @MrMythical I'm using discord.js v13

Comment: So how are you joining with `channel.join`? That method was removed in v13

Comment: @MrMythical I didn't know when doing it, but it works for me anyway, so apparently it's not removed?

Comment: No it is - [Discord.js 13 channel.join is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785098/15781079)

Comment: If `channel.join` is working for you, then you are *not* using discord.js v13. You may want to double check which version you are on. You can easily do so like so: `console.log("Djs version:", require("discord.js").version)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const { createAudioResource, StreamType, createAudioPlayer, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const player = createAudioPlayer()
joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
}).subscribe(player)
let resource = createAudioResource(join('./folder/', '<song_name>.mp3'));

player.play(resource)
```

As you said, you tried to play file named `Bastille_Pompeii.mp3`, so you need to define `resource` like this: `let resource = createAudioResource(join('./musicfiles/', 'Bastille_Pompeii.mp3'));`

Comment: I got stuck here at requiring the '@discordjs/voice' module, i tried both `npm install discordjs/voice` and `npm install @discordjs/voice` but neither worked.


instead this returned the following error: `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/macci/Documents/Programming/JS/CBbot/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

Comment: @MadMisty this error clearly states you should check `package.json`: `Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

Comment: the main entry is defined (as it should as far as I can tell) `"main": "dist/index.js",`

Comment: It worked in the end, thanks! (Had to reinstall the package, something went wrong first time installing it apparently, installed it to the wrong path with the same command)